# Android: Am I using the BroadcastReceiver wrong?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcastreceiver

I would like to describe how the communication in my app works in the hopes that someone can tell me if it's good/bad/just okay design.

My app is single Activity multiple Fragments.  The Activity has several generic functions such as show/hide a Progressbar animation on the screen or showing a Snackbar.  This is functionality that should only be implemented in one place.

My Fragments send broadcasts whenever they need functionality that is not in the Fragment.  For example, if the Fragment wanted to show a Snackbar message,  I would send a broadcast like this:

```
localBroadcastManager.sendBroadcast(new SnackBarIntent("Show this text"));
```

The Activity receives this broadcast, and shows the Snackbar message. Of course, this is a one way message. My Fragment doesn't know if the broadcast was received.  But all in all, it works.  I can send broadcasts from anywhere, a Service, an Adapter, etc. I can also send Broadcasts between Fragments if I wanted.

I understand there are alternatives to this.  There is an EventBus. Or I could pass a reference of the Activity into the Fragment, Adapter, etc.  To me this sounds like a terrible idea that could prevent proper garbage collection.

Then there is RxJava where I guess my fragment subscribes to an Observable that I get from the Activity.

But the question remains, is it bad to use BroadcastReceiver in this way?  And if so, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it wrong?  No, they were meant for things like this.  I'd make sure I was using a local broadcast and not a global one, for efficiency.  Some of the alternatives may provide a nicer API or more features, but they all do more or less the same thing.

I would say that unless the part of the code that broadcasts is really buried that you're better off with interfaces and method calls than broadcasts.  The problem with any kind of event broadcast is that it decouples the sender and receiver.  That can have advantages when you'd otherwise need to pass objects through multiple levels or to places that shouldn't know about that part of the system.  But it has drawbacks in maintenance, especially if multiple places can put similar messages on the same bus.

Comment: Thanks Gabe.  When you say Interfaces, are you saying the Activity should implement an Interface and I would pass that interface into the Fragment?  Having the Fragment hold a reference to the Activity could cause a memory leak, no?